# Count all posts in this category and all sub-categories - ActiveRecord

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

There are two tables in my project: `posts` and `post_categories`.
Each post in the `posts` table has a `post_category_id` relating to `post_categories.id` as fk, and each entry in `post_categories` has a `parent_id` - self-referencing `post_categories.id`.

On the website, the post categories page shows all the posts in each category, but I need it to also count all the posts in each subcategory thereof.

`post_categories` (0 = main menu)

```
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| id  | title         | parent_id |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
| 1   | Machines      | 0         |
| 2   | Vehicles      | 1         |
| 3   | Industrial    | 1         |
| 4   | Road Cars     | 2         |
| 5   | Track Cars    | 2         |
+-----+---------------+-----------+
```

`posts`

```
+-----+--------+------------------+
| id  | title  | post_category_id |
+-----+--------+------------------+
| 1   | Rally  | 5                |
| 2   | F1     | 5                |
| 3   | Vans   | 4                |
| 4   | Trucks | 4                |
+-----+--------+------------------+
```

So far, if there is a category that does not have any posts directly under it, it shows 0 posts, even if the category contains 2 more categories with a total of 50 posts.

I have been spending a lot of time going round in circles with MySQL `RECURSIVE` functions, to no avail. It seems elusively simple, but I can't find an example of a `RECURSIVE` query that takes a second table into consideration and it's impossible to code for a number of layers, as there is no hard limit to how many levels there could be.

To clarify, then, let's assume we are at the Vehicles menu (post_category_id: 2).
My query should:

1. Count all posts having post_category_id = 2 (none in this case).
2. Count all posts having post_category_id IN (4,5) - because post_categories 4 and 5 both have the parent_id = 2.
3. Add up those numbers and give my two columns containing the total number of posts and the number of categories, so I can print:
   `Post Category Title (Contains 30 posts in 6 categories)`

Could anyone provide a recursive solution?

Comment: Can you clarify: Are you looking to give ONE category id and do the counting? Or do you want to run through all the categories and do the count until they are all counted?

Comment: Also in your example where category 2 doesn't have any posts but has 4 posts in child categories, would the answer be "contains 4 posts in 3 categories" or "4 posts in 2 categories". It is ambiguous if you count the parent if it has no individual posts.

Comment: The total number of posts to count should be in the current category and every level below it, but the categories counted do not include the current level, so if the level we are on now has no posts but contains 4 posts in 2 child categories, it should say "4 posts in 2 categories". If I then added 3 posts directly at that level (not in a sub category), it should then say "7 posts in 2 categories". I don't mind about empty categories being counted, because categories will not show up until they contain at least one post and posts are permanent, so empty cats don't occur.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient way but it works. The recursive CTE builds a list of all descendants of the given category (remove the `WHERE` clause from the first query in the CTE to build for all categories):

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (id, descendant, top_level_id) AS (
    SELECT id, FALSE, id
    FROM post_categories
    WHERE id = 2

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pc.id, TRUE, h.top_level_id
    FROM hierarchy h
    JOIN post_categories pc ON h.id = pc.parent_id
)
SELECT
    pc.*,
    SUM(descendant) AS num_categories,
    SUM((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM posts WHERE post_category_id = h.id)) AS num_posts
FROM post_categories pc
JOIN hierarchy h ON h.top_level_id = pc.id
WHERE pc.id = 2
GROUP BY pc.id;
```

For the sample data provided in your question, it outputs:

| id | title | parent_id | num_categories | num_posts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | Vehicles | 1 | 2 | 4 |

If running for all categories you should pre-aggregate the category counts as they will be required multiple times:

```
WITH RECURSIVE hierarchy (id, descendant, top_level_id) AS (
    SELECT id, FALSE, id
    FROM post_categories

    UNION ALL

    SELECT pc.id, TRUE, h.top_level_id
    FROM hierarchy h
    JOIN post_categories pc ON h.id = pc.parent_id
),
cat_counts (id, cnt) AS (
    SELECT pc.id, COUNT(p.id)
    FROM post_categories pc
    LEFT JOIN posts p ON pc.id = p.post_category_id
    GROUP BY pc.id
)
SELECT pc.*, SUM(descendant) AS categories, SUM(cc.cnt) AS num_posts
FROM post_categories pc
JOIN hierarchy h ON h.top_level_id = pc.id
JOIN cat_counts cc ON h.id = cc.id
GROUP BY pc.id;
```

which outputs:

| id | title | parent_id | categories | num_posts |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Machines | NULL | 4 | 4 |
| 2 | Vehicles | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| 3 | Industrial | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 4 | Road Cars | 2 | 0 | 2 |
| 5 | Track Cars | 2 | 0 | 2 |

Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/maVWXlqo)

Comment: Thank you for this. I will give it a try as soon as I get home. It looks promising. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have a couple questions above that will help refine this answer if it is not what you are looking for.

```
def post_and_cat_count(title)
  
  lookup_category = PostCategory.find_by(title: title).id
  child_categories = PostCategory.where(parent_id: lookup_category)

  post_count = Post.where(post_category_id: lookup_category).count + 
  Post.where(post_category_id: child_categories).count

  {posts: post_count, categories: (child_categories.length + 1)}

end

display_counts = post_and_cat_count('Vehicles')
#=> {posts: 4, categories: 3}

puts "Post Category Vehicles (Contains #{display_counts[:posts]} posts in #{display_counts[:categories]} categories)
#=> 'Post Category Vehicles (Contains 4 posts in 3 categories)'
```

I think this is what you are looking for? If you need something more recursive, then you need to expand your question and give a recursive example. By that I mean a situation where the method would call itself and break out of an infinite loop with a `return` clause.

Comment: I think they are actually talking about a recursive CTE - what you're doing will result in a bunch of additional queries.

Comment: They put "ActiveRecord" at the end of the title, and didn't state SQL as a requirement. If that's they case they should edit their question and remove references to AR or Rails. Probably a better question for the Database Admin Stack Exchange.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to make the question as clear as possible. The query needs to be fully recursive in that I have no way to tell how many levels there may end up being. It is for a Rails app, so ot might need translation to AR, but I'm not sure if it's possible due to its complexity. Anyway, thank you for your answer, but I think the first answer may be what I'm looking for. Will update here once I have a chance to try it.